# Warning while installing Angular Material

Tags: angular-material

I installed Angular Material and noticed several warnings on the console. Do I have incompatible or missing libraries?

```
c:/...>npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
npm WARN @angular/cdk@6.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/cdk@6.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@6.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@6.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cdk@6.1.0
+ @angular/material@6.1.0
added 2 packages in 42.598s
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using @angular/material in 6.1.0. This version is designed to work with Angular 6. It appears that you are using an earlier Angular version.

For Angular 5 you could use @angular/material in version 5.x.x by updating your package.json as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    ...
 },
```